# Renaming branch possible?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working on a git for a while (using gitlab.com).
Now I see, that it would be better to use another name for a used branch.

Is it possible to change that branch name - even if it has multiple commits and is already merged to another branch in the past - local and remotely?

Because it is a 'old' branch, which has already being merged, I can't build a new one and delete the old one.

Comment: Old merged branches are usually deleted, why do you need to have a new name for it instead?

Comment: It is the wrong name, which is shown in the network graph (commits -> network)

Comment: Refer: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-local-and-remote-git-branch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change that branch name

```
# use the -m flag for move
git branch -m <oldname> <newname>

# now you have to push the new branch to the server
git push origin <newname>

# delete the old remote branch
git push origin --delete <oldname>
```

---

> Because it is a 'old' branch, which has already being merged, I can't build a new one and delete the old one.

If your branch is merged  and you don't want it any more you can delete it locally:

```
git branch -D <oldname>
```